# Update a value in MongoDB based on its current value

Tags: mongodb

I want to do something like this, but the `this` keyword doesn't seem to be set inside the update statement.

`db.items.update({foo:…}, {$set: {bar: this.foo}}, false, true)`

Do I have to use `eval` to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can't refer to other fields in the modifier.  You'll have to use db.eval.