# Update MongoDB field using value of another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, is it possible to update the value of a field using the value from another field?  The equivalent SQL would be something like:

```
UPDATE Person SET Name = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
```

And the MongoDB pseudo-code would be:

```
db.person.update( {}, { $set : { name : firstName + ' ' + lastName } );
```

Comment: the braces don't match... if i get it to work, i will correct it

Answer (score 561, accepted):

The best way to do this is in version 4.2+ which allows using the aggregation pipeline in the *update* document and the [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline), [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline), or [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)(deprecated in most if not all languages drivers) collection methods.

#### MongoDB 4.2+

Version 4.2 also introduced the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) pipeline stage operator, which is an alias for  [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). I will use `$set` here as it *maps* with what we are trying to achieve.

```
db.collection.<update method>(
    {},
    [
        {"$set": {"name": { "$concat": ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]}}}
    ]
)
```

Note that square brackets in the second argument to the method specify an aggregation pipeline instead of a plain update document because using a simple document will **not** work correctly.

#### MongoDB 3.4+

In 3.4+, you can use `$addFields` and the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation pipeline operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "name": { "$concat": [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } 
        }},
        { "$out": <output collection name> }
    ]
)
```

Note that this *does not update your collection but instead replaces the existing collection or creates a new one.* Also, for update operations that require *"typecasting"*, you will need client-side processing, and depending on the operation, you may need to use the `find()` method instead of the `.aggreate()` method.

### MongoDB 3.2 and 3.0

The way we do this is by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ing our documents and using the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) string aggregation operator to return the concatenated string.
You then iterate the *cursor* and use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator to add the new field to your documents using *bulk operations* for maximum efficiency.

#### Aggregation query:

```
var cursor = db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$project":  { 
        "name": { "$concat": [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } 
    }}
])
```

#### MongoDB 3.2 or newer

You need to use the [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method.

```
var requests = [];
cursor.forEach(document => { 
    requests.push( { 
        'updateOne': {
            'filter': { '_id': document._id },
            'update': { '$set': { 'name': document.name } }
        }
    });
    if (requests.length === 500) {
        //Execute per 500 operations and re-init
        db.collection.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
    }
});

if(requests.length > 0) {
     db.collection.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

#### MongoDB 2.6 and  3.0

From this version, you need to use the now deprecated [`Bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API and its [associated methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/).

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

cursor.snapshot().forEach(function(document) { 
    bulk.find({ '_id': document._id }).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'name': document.name }
    });
    count++;
    if(count%500 === 0) {
        // Excecute per 500 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// clean up queues
if(count > 0) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

#### MongoDB 2.4

```
cursor["result"].forEach(function(document) {
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": document._id }, 
        { "$set": { "name": document.name } }
    );
})
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with the code for "MongoDB 3.2 or newer". Since forEach is async nothing will typically get written in the last bulkWrite.

Comment: 4.2+ Doesn't work. MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'name.$concat' is not valid for storage.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock, I think you had a typo in the query you are running. I suggest you double check.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock It works beautifully. Please test this using the [MongoDB Web Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/)

Comment: For those running into the same problem @JoshWoodcock described: pay attention that the answer for 4.2+ describes an *aggregation pipeline*, so don't miss the *square brackets* in the second parameter!

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing as in this solution but instead of concatenating two strings together, add two numbers together?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Yes, use `$add` instead of `$concat`.  https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add

Comment: @styvane Is it possible to do this using Mongoose?

Comment: [Yes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) @AzamatAbdullaev

Comment: @styvane It only reads data, not for updates.

Comment: How many times are they going to change this before it becomes a joke?

Comment: Until there is no room for improvement I guess:) @ajsp

Comment: Does this work the same way with nodejs driver?

Comment: this is not a valid answer, addfields or set does not add to the collection persistently.

Comment: @codemonkey, you should read the full answer. I failed to see where I mentioned that `$set` and `addFields` are update operators.

Comment: @styvane ok i see it now. just the structure of the answer is a bit misleading for me. it would be more clear if the header "MongoDB 4.2+" was on the top of the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for bulk ie all existing documents. I have a case where need to disp a field on UI but old records dont have that field

Comment: About the solution before 4.2. What if we want to do this using a filter? For example, copy the field if not empty. If I remember correctly, the $out operation works in a way that would cause all filtered-out items to be deleted. Unfortunatelly use use Scalingo which does not support mongo 4.2 due to some licence issue. :( JS is also out of the question because the queries will run in liquibase - which does not support JS.

Comment: can someone solve this using db.runCommand, dollar symbol to refer existing field doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 264):

You should iterate through. For your specific case:

```
db.person.find().snapshot().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.person.update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    name: elem.firstname + ' ' + elem.lastname
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: What happens if another user has changed the document between your find() and your save()?

Comment: As far as I know, MongoDB is not transaction safe

Comment: True, but copying between fields should not require transactions to be atomic.

Comment: It's important to notice that `save()` fully replaces the document. Should use `update()` instead.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona I believe the change you made isn't the correct syntax for the `update` method. Maybe you should use `save` after all.

Comment: How about `db.person.update( { _id: elem._id }, { $set: { name: elem.firstname + ' ' + elem.lastname } } );`

Comment: Works for me when you don't have access to  `db.eval()` due to user access rights

Comment: I created a function called `create_guid` that only produced a unique guid per document when iterating with `forEach` in this way (i.e. simply using `create_guid` in an `update` statement with `mutli=true` caused the same guid to be generated for all documents).  This answer worked perfectly for me. +1

Comment: This could be made more "atomic" by having a query filter such as `{ _id: elem._id, firstname: elem.firstname, lastname: elem.lastname}`, instead of just the `_id` filter. Dunno about performance, partial failures, etc, cause I'm a MongoDB noob, but I think it would have stronger consistency guarantees. Not sure if this would lock the collection or each document as you loop through, but might be worth checking out.

Comment: Can this be done if I simply want to update a field on a document with a certain `id` using another field this document contains. It is this latter field that I am having trouble extracting.

Comment: This is works, thanks. But isn't there a faster / more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @EdMelo: is there anything wrong with using `save()` if no other updates occur to the database while the `forEach` runs? Also, [`snapshot` is deprecated since v3.6](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2809).

Answer (score 108):

Apparently there is a way to do this efficiently since MongoDB 3.4, see [styvane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/332100).

---

**Obsolete answer below**

You cannot refer to the document itself in an update (yet). You'll need to iterate through the documents and update each document using a function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958) for an example, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343147/1269037) for server-side `eval()`.

Comment: Is this still valid today?

Comment: @ChristianEngel: It appears so. I wasn't able to find anything in the MongoDB docs that mentions a reference to the current document in an `update` operation. [This related feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458) is still unresolved as well.

Comment: Is it still valid in April 2017? Or there are already new features which can do this?

Comment: @Kim It looks like it is still valid. Also, the [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458) that @niels-van-der-rest pointed out back in 2013 is still in `OPEN`.

Comment: this is not a valid answer anymore, have a look at @styvane answer

Answer (score 49):

For a database with high activity, you may run into issues where your updates affect actively changing records and for this reason I recommend using **snapshot()**

```
db.person.find().snapshot().forEach( function (hombre) {
    hombre.name = hombre.firstName + ' ' + hombre.lastName; 
    db.person.save(hombre); 
});
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/

Comment: What happens if another user edited the person between the find() and save()? I have a case where multiple calls can be done to the same object changing them based on their current values. The 2nd user should have to wait with reading until the 1st is done with saving. Does this accomplish that?

Comment: About the `snapshot()`:  `Deprecated in the mongo Shell since v3.2. Starting in v3.2, the $snapshot operator is deprecated in the mongo shell. In the mongo shell, use cursor.snapshot() instead.` [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/#cursor.snapshot)

Comment: Nice method. It might be very slow looping through thousands or tens of thousands of objects.

Answer (score 41):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update/creation of a field based on another field:

```
// { firstName: "Hello", lastName: "World" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { name: { $concat: [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } } }]
)
// { "firstName" : "Hello", "lastName" : "World", "name" : "Hello World" }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in our case all documents).
- The second part `[{ $set: { name: { ... } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator and an alias of `$addFields`.

Comment: Worked for me. Was assigning one field to another without concatenation and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: what is the difference between your first point and your third?  {} mean all doc then why { multi: true }

Comment: @Coder17 the first part `{}` is a filtering part: for instance you might want to update `doc1` and `doc2` but not `doc3`. Without the third part, by default, the update will be applied only on 1 document for instance `doc1`, and `doc2` wouldn't be updated. Note that you can also use `db.collection.updateMany` to get rid of the third parameter.

Comment: at this point we'd use updateMany

Answer (score 17):

Regarding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423151/7948731), the snapshot function is deprecated in version 3.6, according to this [update](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2809). So, on version 3.6 and above, it is possible to perform the operation this way:

```
db.person.find().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.person.update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    name: elem.firstname + ' ' + elem.lastname
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 9):

`update()` method takes aggregation pipeline as parameter like

```
db.collection_name.update(
  {
    // Query
  },
  [
    // Aggregation pipeline
    { "$set": { "id": "$_id" } }
  ],
  {
    // Options
    "multi": true // false when a single doc has to be updated
  }
)
```

The field can be set or unset with existing values using the aggregation pipeline.

**Note**: use `$` with field name to specify the field which has to be read.

Comment: Only works MongoDB 4.2 and later.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/404699

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The solution works for MongoDb 4.2+ versions

Answer (score 8):

I tried the above solution but I found it unsuitable for large amounts of data. I then discovered the stream feature:

```
MongoClient.connect("...", function(err, db){
    var c = db.collection('yourCollection');
    var s = c.find({/* your query */}).stream();
    s.on('data', function(doc){
        c.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {name : doc.firstName + ' ' + doc.lastName}}, function(err, result) { /* result == true? */} }
    });
    s.on('end', function(){
        // stream can end before all your updates do if you have a lot
    })
})
```

Comment: How is this different? Will the steam be throttled by the update activity? Do you have any reference to it? The Mongo docs are quite poor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what we came up with for copying one field to another for ~150_000 records. It took about 6 minutes, but is still significantly less resource intensive than it would have been to instantiate and iterate over the same number of ruby objects.

```
js_query = %({
  $or : [
    {
      'settings.mobile_notifications' : { $exists : false },
      'settings.mobile_admin_notifications' : { $exists : false }
    }
  ]
})

js_for_each = %(function(user) {
  if (!user.settings.hasOwnProperty('mobile_notifications')) {
    user.settings.mobile_notifications = user.settings.email_notifications;
  }
  if (!user.settings.hasOwnProperty('mobile_admin_notifications')) {
    user.settings.mobile_admin_notifications = user.settings.email_admin_notifications;
  }
  db.users.save(user);
})

js = "db.users.find(#{js_query}).forEach(#{js_for_each});"
Mongoid::Sessions.default.command('$eval' => js)
```

Answer (score 0):

With **MongoDB version 4.2+**, updates are more flexible as it allows the use of aggregation pipeline in its `update`, `updateOne` and `updateMany`. You can now transform your documents using the aggregation operators then update without the need to explicity state the `$set` command (instead we use `$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$$ROOT"}`)

Here we use the aggregate query to extract the timestamp from MongoDB's ObjectID "_id" field and update the documents (I am not an expert in SQL but I think SQL does not provide any auto generated ObjectID that has timestamp to it, you would have to automatically create that date)

```
var collection = "person"

agg_query = [
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "_last_updated" : {
                "$toDate" : "$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$$ROOT"
        } 
    }
]

db.getCollection(collection).updateMany({}, agg_query, {upsert: true})
```

Comment: You don't need `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$$ROOT" } }`; it means replacing the document by itself, which is pointless. If you replace `$addFields` by its alias `$set` and `updateMany` which is one of the aliases for `update`, then you get to the exact same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551339/9297144) above.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Guihot for the comment. The reason why ```$replaceRoot``` is used because we needed to use the ```$toDate``` query, while ```$set``` does not provide us a way to use ```$toDate```

Answer (score 0):

(I would have posted this as a comment, but couldn't)

For anyone who lands here trying to update one field using another in the document with the c# driver...
I could not figure out how to use any of the `UpdateXXX` methods and their associated overloads since they take an `UpdateDefinition` as an argument.

```
// we want to set Prop1 to Prop2
class Foo { public string Prop1 { get; set; } public string Prop2 { get; set;} } 

void Test()
{ 
     var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Foo>();
     update.Set(x => x.Prop1, <new value; no way to get a hold of the object that I can find>)
}
```

As a workaround, I found that you can use the `RunCommand` method on an `IMongoDatabase` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update).

```
var command = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "update", "CollectionToUpdate" },
            { "updates", new BsonArray 
                 { 
                       new BsonDocument
                       {
                            // Any filter; here the check is if Prop1 does not exist
                            { "q", new BsonDocument{ ["Prop1"] = new BsonDocument("$exists", false) }}, 
                            // set it to the value of Prop2
                            { "u", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { ["$set"] = new BsonDocument("Prop1", "$Prop2") }}},
                            { "multi", true }
                       }
                 }
            }
        };

 database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

### MongoDB 4.2+ Golang

```golang
result, err := collection.UpdateMany(ctx, bson.M{},
    mongo.Pipeline{
        bson.D{{"$set",
          bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$concat": []string{"$lastName", " ", "$firstName"}}}
    }},
)
```